# cannot read property 'apply' of undefined gulp

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, npm-install, gulp-sass

I am trying to use the ng-factory generator to scaffold a new project to build an angularjs component. After the project has been created with the yo ng-factory command, I tried to run it using the gulp serve task but found the following error:

```
c:\projects\bywebclient>gulp serve
[11:20:51] Loading C:\projects\bywebclient\gulp_tasks\browsersync.js
[11:20:52] Loading C:\projects\bywebclient\gulp_tasks\karma.js
[11:20:57] Loading C:\projects\bywebclient\gulp_tasks\misc.js
[11:20:57] Loading C:\projects\bywebclient\gulp_tasks\webpack.js
[11:21:07] Using gulpfile c:\projects\bywebclient\gulpfile.js
C:\Users\ATUL KALE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129
gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
```

^

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>   at C:\Users\ATUL KALE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:
>   19
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>   at Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
>   at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
>   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
>   at bootstrap_node.js:467:3

Am I missing something? I already tried to run again the npm install

Thanks,
Atul Kale

Answer (score 93):

Try to **reinstall** gulp-cli :

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

Comment: As mentioned by @ofribt on his answer, after reinstall open new terminal window and retry there.

Comment: I had to add --force at the end to get this working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

And important: after running that command, open a new terminal so it'll take effect.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade to 4.0 like this:

```
npm install --save-dev github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall the global gulp installation and local gulp-cli installation. While keeping global gulp-cli and local gulp packages.

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall -g gulp-cli

npm install -g gulp-cli
npm install --save-dev github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0
```

Comment: The above code uninstalls `gulp-cli` **globally**, while your explanation recommends uninstalling it locally. Am I mistaken in seeing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 2):

I get below error everytime i run

```
npm install gulp -g --save
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

```
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

I tried:

`npm i -g gulp-cli`

and it works for me.

If again i run

```
npm install gulp -g --save
```

the above error returns. I noted when i first installed Gulp it was saved in my package.json but now it's absent.

Answer (score 1):

I tried uninstalling both `gulp` and `gulp-cli` from my machine (locally and globally), but after uninstall `gulp -v`, it still showed `Gulp CLI 3.9.1`, even in new terminal window.
In the end, these are the steps that finally worked for me (seems like CLI simply got cached hard):

1. Navigate to your project and delete `node_modules` folder.
2. Run following:

```
npm uninstall gulp --global
npm uninstall gulp-cli --global
apt-get remove npm
apt-get remove nodejs
apt-get install nodejs
apt-get install npm
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

3. Navigate to your project and run:
   `npm install`
4. Close current terminal, open new one and check for success:
   `gulp -v`

Should say `CLI version 2.1.0` (as of time of writing).

Now you can run your gulp tasks without that error :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an automated script which was doing `npm install gulp (...)` and until v3.9x it was fine.

After some time, that naive install would pick v4.0.0, which breaks my CI.

Changing the script to do `npm install gulp@3.9.1` reverted things back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall gulp and gulp-cli, to install the last version.

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall -g gulp-cli

npm install -g gulp-cli
npm install -g gulp
```

And then, close the terminal and open new.

*This command no longer works: `npm install --save-dev github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0`